# Почему TypeScript не ругается на ошибку?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Изучаю TS. Есть компонент с таким кодом:

```
function Search() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<number | string>('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    searchMovie(input)
      .then((movies: Movies) => {
        console.log('movies:', movies)
        dispatch(searchAction(movies));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
export interface Movies {
  films: string[]
}
```

Почему в компоненте в функции searchMovie TS  не ругается на movies: Movies?
Фактические в movies попадает объект с нужным мне ключом films.

Функция searchMovie

```
import { BASE_URL } from '../utils/constants';

function searchMovie(keyword) {
  return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/search-by-keyword?keyword=${keyword}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-API-KEY': '6f26fa-08c4-47vv-90cb-cb534e2732b4',
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    }
    return Promise.reject('Ошибка с фронта');
  });
}

export { searchMovie };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вроде все правильно. что именно не так и на что должен ругаться тайпскрипт?

Comment: я понимаю так: в movies приходит объект с ключом films и массивом объектов, а в интерфейсе прописан массив строк у ключа films...должно же ругаться? я хочу ошибку спровоцировать чтобы лучше понять как это все работает

Comment: тогда смотри что у тебя в функции `searchMovie` происходит.

Comment: Основная причина, наверняка, в том, что делается запрос, результат запроса `any`  а `any` можно присвоить любому типу

Comment: я добавил функцию searchMovies в первый пост. Мне нужно там типизировать, а не в промисах как я ранее пытался?

Comment: Функция `searchMovie` должна возвращать что-то вроде такого `Promise<Movies>`. Иначе Promise разрешится с неизвестным типом, который наверняка и будет `any`, как это и сказал @Grundy.

Comment: `res.json()` возвращает `Promise<any>` поэтому по сути и результат его будет `any`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, формально функция сейчас и возвращает что-то вроде такого. Мешается то, что никто не знает без проверок что именно будет результатом `.json()`

Comment: @qweezz. посмотри в сторону [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: @Grundy Это JS возвращает `Promise<Movies>`, TS, в свою очередь, не знает что может возвратить `fetch`. И если запрос явно нацелен на Movies(а по названию функции это видимо так и есть), то в searchMovie надо указать возвращаемый тип `searchMovie(...):Promise<Movies>`.

Comment: я сделал изменения только в одной строке, написал так: function searchMovie(keyword: string | number): Promise<Movies> . Никаких ошибок, ничего и нигде

Comment: @qweezz _я сделал изменения(c)_ В представленном коде ошибок и не будет. Странно почему она тут вообще должна быть. Ошибка была бы, если б `searchAction` принимал конкретный тип несоответствующий `films:string[]`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, ну не, добавка в декларации `:Promise<Movies>` никак не поможет, так как в нее вполне можно вернуть `Promise<any>` и проверка типов не сработает. Единственный вариант, проверять что именно пришло в json, вручную, и кидать исключение, если нужно.

Comment: @Grundy Разумеется не поможет. Тут немного другое: @qweezz запутался где кончается грань TypeScript и что в консоли он уже не увидит никаких ошибок. Я лишь упомянул о необходимости указания типа, для дальнейшей работы с кодом - передачи ответа(с установленным типом) в другие функции. @ _"кидать исключение"(с)_ - собственно так и поступают всякие `REST|GraphQL`